# How to detect button press and add it to mySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this issue. I'm new and trying to make this work but failing to achieve it. can anyone please help me out. I have 4 machines and each of them have ON/OFF buttons. so what I want is that when I turn on/off the machine no'3 button it should show up on MySQL database showing which button was pressed and the machine. I'm using html, php and mySQL for this. I'm not sure what to add for php script. thanks

**HTML:**

```
<form action="db.php">
<input class="buttonOne" type="submit" name="onButton" value="ON" />
<input class="buttonA "type="submit" name="offButton" value="OFF" />
<input class="buttonTwo" type="submit" name="onButton" value="ON" />
<input class="buttonB "type="submit" name="offButton" value="OFF" />
<input class="buttonThree" type="submit" name="onButton" value="ON" />
<input class="buttonC "type="submit" name="offButton" value="OFF" />
<input class="buttonFour" type="submit" name="onButton" value="ON" />
<input class="buttonD "type="submit" name="offButton" value="OFF" />
</form>
```

**db.php:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['onButton'])) {
    echo "On button was pressed.";
} else if (isset($_POST['offButton']){
    echo "Off button was pressed.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. You want to add a database record for every button that is pressed?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for getting data into the db when pressing a button. You would first want to know what you wanna store in the db. Do you just want to know if it is on/off or do you wanna keep track of the history like a log? This determines your DB design. Think about such things first.

Comment: Use AJAX. It will help

Comment: @Oldskool Hello there, I basically want that when i press ON or OFF it will add it to the database saying which button was pressed and which machine's button was pressed. make sense?. thanks

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest Hello, Yes i just want to know if the on or off button pressed and the machine number. thanks

Comment: @NanaPartykar I'm not very familiar with AJAX ...that's why i want it to do with html and php only.

Comment: Using AJAX will makes things easier, and it will look and feel nicer to a user. However, I will provide you with some code soon, hang on.

Comment: I also recommend using AJAX but if you want to do it with php you can not name all the buttons the same. You will not know witch one you have selected if you get a post like onButton = ON. You can do it with an array names that are the same or change the names. But again use Ajax. Here is a example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186060/ajax-form-with-multiple-submit-buttons-and-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP` and `AJAX` for this. `AJAX` would make things a lot easier, faster, and a loot nicer to the user. However, you said you didn't want to use `AJAX`. So here we go:

First of all, determine what you want to store into the database. Just know if a certain machine is on/off or keep track of the history. You told us you just need an on/off status. Therefor your db will need a table with the following columns: `id`, `status`.

The `id` should be your primary key. This means it must be unique for example. You should just know the basics of databases for this. Your `status` can be a `TINYINT(1)` respresenting a boolean. (0 is false/off, 1 is true/on).

Now you can use this for your **HTML**:

```
<form method="post" action="db.php">
  <p>Machine 1: <input type="submit" name="1" value="Turn On"> <output>Off</output></p>
  <p>Machine 2: <input type="submit" name="2" value="Turn On"> <output>Off</output></p>
  <p>Machine 3: <input type="submit" name="3" value="Turn On"> <output>Off</output></p>
  <p>Machine 4: <input type="submit" name="4" value="Turn On"> <output>Off</output></p>
</form>
```

You could use a button for each machine like here. Or as you tried, use a button for off and a button for on, on each machine, creating 8 buttons. Not that nice right? You want to keep things minimized. This will spare space and look nicer.

Now while using 4 buttons you will need to change it's value (as well as the output tag it's content which can be used to show the status, and to make things fancier you can add a class to it, making the text green or red etc). This is something you can work on yourself as a next task.

For putting things into a database you can use multiple ways to go. [Read about them here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Next you want to use this code in your **`db.php`**:

```
if(isset($_POST['1'])) {
    // Put logic and query here to toggle machine 1
}
```

Of course you will have to check if the machine is on/off and toggle it.

For more help on this you can google, because there are lots of tutorials out there, and now you know some of the terms.

You might wanna end up with something like this:

```css
.on {
  color: red;
}
.off {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="db.php">
  <p>Machine 1: <input type="submit" name="1" value="Turn Off"> <output class="on">On</output></p>
  <p>Machine 2: <input type="submit" name="2" value="Turn On"> <output class="off">Off</output></p>
  <p>Machine 3: <input type="submit" name="3" value="Turn Off"> <output class="on">On</output></p>
  <p>Machine 4: <input type="submit" name="4" value="Turn On"> <output class="off">Off</output></p>
</form>
```